# How can I clear items with a custom name using a command block? (using to "lock/unlock doors)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm in Minecraft Pocket Edition. My command block is set to repeating and always active. I have it attached to a comparator that runs into a block with an iron door on top. The command input I have is

/clear @p[x=~0,y=~0,z=~-2,r=2] tripwire_hook 0 0 {display:{Name:”key”}}

The IDEA is to set off the command block whenever the tripwire hook is within 2 blocks of the door. This works fine UNTIL I try adding the custom name. The Previous Output box keeps saying:

Syntax error: Unexpected “{“: at “_hook 0 0 >>{<

any ideas on how to fix this syntax error? If you don't, do you have any other ways to lock a door and open it when you have a custom names item?

Comment: PE has no NBT .

Answer (score 0):

This may work if you have patience and time. Try to build this thing that you need to drop a specific item (I recommend a written book) in front of the door, which turns off a repeating command block that is constantly cloning a closed door to that location. If all goes well, dropping a book then trying to open the door and it works, then you are good!

The command I recommend is 
/clone (coordinates of the bottom half of a closed door) (coordinates of the top half of door) (where you want the door to be)

Set it to a repeating but requires red stone command block
If you don’t know how to make such thing, go to YouTube to look for answers